# Dart - Allow any params for base method

Tags: flutter, dart

I need a base method that can take any params. Can you do this without creating a new class for the param? I think the only way is to specify one param and to create a type for that param? So I have done this:

The method in the base class:

```
void onSubmitPressed(dynamic args) {}
```

And the extending class:

```
  @override
  void onSubmitPressed(dynamic args) {
    args.passwordViewModel.email = entity.email;
    args.passwordViewModel.nickName = entity.nickName;

    args.controller.nextPage(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
        curve: Curves.easeInOutCubic);

    putLocal();
    super.onSubmitPressed(args);
  }
```

It gets called like this:

```
viewModel.onSubmitPressed(SubmitArgs(controller, passwordViewModel))

class SubmitArgs {
  const SubmitArgs(this.controller, this.passwordViewModel);
  final PageController controller;
  final RegisterPasswordViewModel passwordViewModel;
}
```

It works. I don't really like having to create the Args class though. So I'm keen to know if I can avoid that? Also, if I do have to create it, I may as well make it type-safe with generics rather than just say `dynamic` in the base. I try to use generics to make it type-safe like this:

```
void onSubmitPressed<T>(T args) {}

 @override
  void onSubmitPressed<SubmitArgs>(SubmitArgs args) {
    args.passwordViewModel.email = entity.email;
    args.passwordViewModel.nickName = entity.nickName;

    args.controller.nextPage(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
        curve: Curves.easeInOutCubic);

    putLocal();
    super.onSubmitPressed(args);
  }
```

It doesn't seem to know that it is extending a base class and says:

> The getter 'passwordViewModel' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.

Can I either use generics to make it type-safe or even better, avoid the strong typing altogether and just pass in anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for **"Variable number of function arguments**" language feature (like [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs) in Kotlin), Dart doesn't have one. [Here is](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1014) actual feature request.

You can use List as function argument:

```
  void onSubmitPressed(List<dynamic> args) {
    final arg0 = args[0];
    final arg1 = args[1];
  }
```

But as you noticed this way is not type safe. So it would be better to use generics.

**As for generics**, I recommended you to use class-scoped generics in your case:

```
abstract class BaseClass<T> {
  void onSubmitPressed(T args);
}

class Class1 extends BaseClass<SubmitArgs> {
  @override
  void onSubmitPressed(SubmitArgs args) {
    // TODO: implement onSubmit
  }
}
```

In addition you can use generic constraints for you parameters classes to make your code more specific:

```
abstract class Args {
  const Args();
}

class SubmitArgs extends Args {
  const SubmitArgs(this.controller, this.passwordViewModel);
  final PageController controller;
  final RegisterPasswordViewModel passwordViewModel;
}

abstract class BaseClass<T extends Args> {
  void onSubmitPressed(T args);
}
```

#### UPDATE

If you don't want to pass arguments to `onSubmitPressed` func for specific subclass, you can make args parameter optional:

```
abstract class BaseClass<T> {
  void onSubmitPressed({T args});
}
```

Subclass that has no arguments for this function would be like this:

```
class Class2 extends BaseClass {
  @override
  void onSubmitPressed({void args}) {
    // TODO: implement onSubmit
  }
}
```

Call `onSubmitPressed` without args from elsewhere:

```
final class2 = Class2();
class2.onSubmitPressed();
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks nice. Does this work with passing in a void for when there are no args? I have had to remove `extends Args` from your solution to allow passing the void type, and do this: ` @override
  void onSubmitPressed(void args) {
    super.onSubmitPressed(args);`. It feels a little bit awkward explicitly passing args that are void, but is this necessary?

Comment: Yes, you can use `void`. It's not necessary to remove `extends Args`, see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you. It is complaining that `Class2` is not giving a type generic to `BaseClass`. It complains twice: 'dynamic' doesn't extend 'Args'.
Try using a type that is or is a subclass of 'Args'. And also: The type 'Class2' is declared with 2 type parameters, but 1 type arguments were given.
Try adjusting the number of type arguments to match the number of type parameters. (FYI, I have another type param so that's why it said 2 type parameters).

Comment: Oh yes, finally you were right about `extend Args` because `dynamic` or `void` doesn't extend 'Args'. Lets try to remove the generic constraint.
As for `Class2 is not giving a type generic to BaseClass` - is it runtime error or static analyzer issue?

Comment: can I find it here? https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/

Comment: No it's "wrong_number_of_type_arguments" which is not there

Comment: I have no such warning, so unfortunately it would be difficult to find a reason for me(

Comment: Maybe different version:

Flutter 1.22.4 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 1aafb3a8b9 (5 weeks ago) • 2020-11-13 09:59:28 -0800
Engine • revision 2c956a31c0
Tools • Dart 2.10.4